# Getting Boot Error When Booting 13.04 live ISO

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb

I'm currently running 13.04 ubuntu gnome edition and i want to go to a x64 version of regular ubuntu. Im using the startup disk creator to make my bootable disk and i've even tried unetbootin but that give me the same error message on boot: "Boot Error". I have set my BIOS to boot usb devices first, and the only usb conencted is the one with the bootable file system in it, and i am at a loss. I dont know what to try next so i turned here. Also, i have booted from usb many times before on this cpu so i am sure that it is capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had problems with unetbootin & startup disk creator. Then I made a bootable USB using dd.

So first plug-in the usb device and run the following command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will give you list all the partitions you have. check the partitions carefully. Most probably /dev/sdb is the usb one(if no other usb storage is plugged-in).You should see something like this(if it is a 8 GB pendrive)

Disk /dev/sdb: 8.0 GB,blabla.....

Now to make a bootable usb

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdb
```

**BE CAREFUL** with of option. If you carelessly put something wrong you will be doomed.

If you have windows installed, you can use [LiLi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/linux-live-usb-creator/)

Comment: do i have to format the drive with a certian file system first?

Comment: and the file path should be /path/of/iso/nameoffile.iso right?